# How to upload more then 100 mb data on git hub using ubuntu desktop

Tags: github

Here is problem when I make change in my local to upload on git hub

```
 remote: error: GH001: Large files detected.
 remote: error: Trace: 7e2842b7648904965d2e954cc96d9410
 remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
 remote: error: File _logs/access.log is 119.62 MB;
 this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100 MB
 To https://github.com/SevenVerbs/ARS.git
 ! [remote rejected] stage -> stage (pre-receive hook declined)
 error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/SevenVerbs/ARS.git'
```

Answer (score 1):

[The link on your error message](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/) clearly says github doesn't support upload larger than 100mb

It's also very suspicious why would you want to include log files `_logs/access.log` into your source code. The filename strongly suggest it isn't a source code

Comment: Even I remove this file from local I got same problem if suppose I want to commit more files that are less than 100 mb

Comment: you need to untrack the files from git. Do this by excluding log files on .gitignore and removing the already-tracked files using `git rm --cached`

Comment: I am new on this can you elaborate it by command that I got success

Comment: In terminal gitignore and  .gitignore file is generated 
and in .git folder /info/exlude  and # _logs/access.log in this file and git rm --cached

Comment: pankaj@kindlebit-desktop:/var/www/zend_project3$ git rm --cached
usage: git rm [options] [--] <file>...

    -n, --dry-run         dry run
    -q, --quiet           do not list removed files
    --cached              only remove from the index
    -f, --force           override the up-to-date check
    -r                    allow recursive removal
    --ignore-unmatch      exit with a zero status even if nothing matched